# Problema ao Desligar Computador pelo Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows

Estou utilizando os seguinte código para desligar o computador via programa do Delphi:

```
//Adicionar à cláusula Uses, Shellapi e digitar os parâmetros abaixo no clique de um botão por exemplo:

// Desliga o Windows
ExitWindowsEx(EWX_SHUTDOWN, 0);
```

Porém o computador não desliga, ele apenas finaliza a sessão e abre uma nova.

Existe alguma alternativa para o computador desligar totalmente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
WinExec(PAnsiChar('cmd.exe /c shutdown -s -t 10'), sw_normal);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Comment: Esse @Denied é muito brabo mesmo. Obrigado!